# Convert a slice to native (endianness) integer

Tags: type-conversion, endianness, d

I have a slice of bytes (which I know that are an integer saved as little endian) and I want to convert them to an integer.

When I had a static-sized array it was no problem, but now I have a slice (`ubyte[]`).

Is it possible to still convert it to an integer, e.g. in this fashion?

```
ubyte[] bytes = ...;
uint native = littleEndianSliceToNative!uint(bytes);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking further what Adam has written, you can write a simple function like

```
T sliceToNative(T)(ubyte[] slice) if(isNumeric!T) {
    const uint s = T.sizeof,
               l = min(cast(uint)s, slice.length);

    ubyte[s] padded;
    padded[0 .. l] = slice[0 .. l]; 

    return littleEndianToNative!T(padded);
}
```

You could even make the `littleEndianToNative` a generic type too so you mirror all the operations on arrays for slices.

Answer (score 5):

Just slice the slice explicitly to the appropriate size:

```
import std.bitmanip;
void main() {
    ushort i = 12345;
    ubyte[2] swappedI = nativeToLittleEndian(i);
    ubyte[] slice = swappedI;

    alias Target = ushort; // make this a template param for a generic function
    assert(i == littleEndianToNative!Target(slice[0..Target.sizeof])); // the [0..Target.sizeof]
}
```

That should work for any size needed.

Comment: could you rewrite your code to a generic function (like the one I wished for in my question) please? See I don't know the size (`0..2` in your code) until runtime, because sometimes I wiil want to get 1 byte and return a  byte, other times 4 bytes and return an int..

Comment: the 2 is just the size of the target type, so replace it with `ushort.sizeof` then you can make a generic function by making the ushort a template parameter too.

Comment: Ok, I see. Rewrite this into `littleEndianSliceToNative` and I accept!